# Automatic reloading is inconsistent on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am using [Automatic Reloading](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#automatic-reloading) when developing so the app always reloads itself every time I save any of the Javascript files on the project.

There aren't any problems on iPhone since it reloads the app on every file save. But on Android it does not pick up changes every time. Maybe about half of the time. Now my workaround is to save file multiple times (smashing save button) so Android notices that the Javascript bundle has changed.

Anyone else have experienced this behaviour also?

Comment: What is live reload? What is reloaded? In what?

Comment: It is this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#automatic-reloading :D